# Haskell: Get data constructor name as string

Tags: haskell, reflection, ghc, generic-programming, deriving

Let us say we have

```
data D = X Int | Y Int Int | Z String
```

I wish to have a function `getDConst`

```
getDConst :: D -> String
```

that returns either "X", "Y", or "Z", according to the data constructor used for its input. Is there a generic way to write this without having to do `case` on every data constructor? (I am ok with solutions relying on `Data.Typeable` or something similar)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the solution myself, but leaving this question to help others:

```
import Data.Data
data D = X Int | Y Int Int deriving (Data,Typeable)

let result = show $ toConstr (X 3) -- result contains what we wanted
```

Comment: If anyone else also gets an error with this: Try adding `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}` to the beginning of your file. It's necessary in GHC when you derive Data and Typeable.

Comment: You can also use `showConstr` instead of `show`.  They do the exact same thing but `showConstr` has less of a risk of being used on the wrong type

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use `Typeable`, you can also do this with `Show`.

```
getDConst :: D -> String
getDConst = head . words . show
```

`Show` will not output all the fields, because it is lazy. You can test it runing this code in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> data D = D [Int] deriving (Show)
Prelude> getDConst $ D [1..]
"D"
```

Comment: You might also want to implement a custom show output that does not involve the constructor.

Comment: `show` is lazy, so this probably won't be very slow. Notice how `take 5 (show (Just undefined))` works fine.

Comment: You mean `words`, not `unwords`. (Actually, I'd write something like `takeWhile (/=' ') . show`)

Comment: if somebody modifies the way show is implemented by default it does not work... this solution relies on a convention

Answer (score -1):

I have a much basic answer to the question without going through imports or whatever. It's Just a simple mere function.

let's say I have the following data. The repetitive **Int** in the data definition is intentional because I will use the don't care symbol afterwards:

```
data YES_NO_CANCEL = YES Int | NO Int Int | CANCEL Int Int Int
```

then you can make a function as :

```
extractDataType :: YES_NO_CANCEL -> String
extractDataType (YES _) = "YES"
extractDataType (NO _ _) = "NO"
extractDataType (CANCEL _ _ _) = "CANCEL"
```

Comment: This answer reminds me of a joke: A mathematician takes a walk over a foggy field when suddenly a low-flying balloon comes in sight.  A balloon passenger shouts down to him: "Sir, can you tell us where we are?"  The mathematician shouts back: "Yes, of course.  You are in a balloon."
*Correct, but entirely useless.*