# List constructor names of a Haskell type?

Tags: haskell, reflection

`conNameOf` allows me to display the constructor name of a given piece of data, given that type is an instance of `Generic`.

What I'd like is something similar. For a given type, I want to get the full list of constructor names. For example:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
  deriving (Generic)

-- constrNames (Proxy :: Proxy Nat) == ["Z", "S"]
```

Does something like `constrNames` exist? If not, how can I write it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297380/67579 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179380/getting-the-data-constructor-name-as-a-string-using-ghc-generics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `conNames` from module `Generics.Deriving.ConNames` in package `generic-deriving` provides this functionality.  It takes a term of the given type, though its value is not used, so you can use `undefined`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Generics.Deriving.ConNames
import Data.Proxy

data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Generic)

main = print $ conNames (undefined :: Nat)
```

gives:

```
λ> main
["Z","S"]
```